# How to get a linux distribution (preferably Ubuntu) installed in a USB stick bootable both EFI and legacy mods?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, grub

I am trying to achieve something somehow challenging. I have a fairly fast and large USB stick (SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 16GB) which I'd like to use in an unorthodox way:

1. I need a partition with a size around 1 GB, which can be readed by both Windows and Linux (as you may know, previous versions of Windows do not get along with multi-partitioned USB sticks very well. Or should I say, at all? They read only the first partition and ignore the rest)
2. I need a Linux distribution (preferably Ubuntu) installed in the stick
3. I need this stick to be bootable both in EFI enabled and legacy machines.

Installing Ubuntu to the disk was simple enough, and speed of the stick is better than I expected. But I was not able to boot the stick from a non-UEFI machine. Machine simply does not read the stick and keeps hanging on a full-black screen.

So, my question is:

- Is what I try to achieve even possible?
- If so, do I need a special partitioning scheme? I'm ok with doing a fresh installation.
- Can I install grub in both UEFI and legacy mods? If so, how?

Comment: Just using a live USB might be easier, especially if you use persistence or can customize it. MX-Linux, AntiX, and I think Puppy has great customization tools, like "set up the live system then create an ISO or bootable USB with a click" easy & they should boot EFI

Comment: I thought that, but I'll modify system files, install software etc. So a live usb with persistence won't cut.

Comment: Also, I'd like to learn about the grub in the process, so I'l keep trying to do it :)

Comment: The live USB's boot with syslinux (or isolinux?) or grub depending on what's supported. And you do know that persistence is what lets a live USB (or DVD, any ro ISO in some cases) install programs & change files?

Comment: I thought that persistence only allows to store files in /home, it is good to know. But I also need a seperate partition on the drive, which is something I cannot have with a live USB w/ persistence created by automated installers.

Comment: Like I said, look into MX-Linux's live USB. It creates two partitions by default, I think the second one is for EFI support, but I don't think anything's stopping you from resizing &making more partitions

Comment: I appreciate all info given, but that is kind of going around the problem. What I actually want to do is to find out whether it is possible or not, and if possible, learn how to do it. Learning part is the real reason I asked this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is what I try to achieve even possible?

Yes!

> If so, do I need a special partitioning scheme? I'm ok with doing a fresh installation.

You will need a special partitioning scheme.  It may be possible to modify your existing one to fit (all you need to add is a tiny 1MiB BIOS boot partition), but I'll outline the necessary partitioning scheme below.

> Can I install grub in both UEFI and legacy mods? If so, how?

You just need to install GRUB for each mode.  Below are instructions for Ubuntu and Debian.

---

### Setup

Here are from-scratch instructions on installing Ubuntu in both UEFI and legacy boot modes.  These instructions work on any disk, not just USB ones.

This guide assumes that **you want to start from scratch** and your disk is `/dev/sdX`.  Replace `/dev/sdX` with your disk block device.

1. Remove all partitions to get a clean slate:

   ```
   sgdisk --zap-all /dev/sdX
   ```
2. Create a GPT partition table on your disk:

   ```
   sgdisk --mbrtogpt /dev/sdX
   ```
3. You have a requirement of a 1GB partition at the beginning of your flash drive, so here's the command to make a 1GiB partition (note: [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) instead of GB):

   ```
   sgdisk --new 3::+1G --typecode 3:0700 /dev/sdX
   ```
4. Create a BIOS boot partition.  This is necessary to add EFI support on legacy boot.

   ```
   sgdisk --new 1::+1M --typecode 1:ef02 /dev/sdX
   ```
5. Create an EFI system partition:

   ```
   sgdisk --new 2::+50M --typecode 2:ef00 /dev/sdX
   ```
6. Create the data partition where you'll install Ubuntu:

   ```
   sgdisk --new 4::+ --typecode 4:8300 /dev/sdX
   ```
7. Install Ubuntu on the flash drive, using the partitioning scheme already set above.

   **Proceed to the next step now only if you do not want to use the graphical Ubuntu installer.**

   If you do want to use the graphical Ubuntu installer, do so now using the partitioning scheme already created, then come back here and run these commands:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdX4 /mnt
   mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev
   mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
   mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys
   chroot /mnt /bin/bash --login
   ```

   Since you used the graphical installer, skip to step 17.
8. Create a file system for Ubuntu on `/dev/sdX4`, the data partition we just created:

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX4
   ```
9. Mount the new file system to a temporary path:

   ```
   mount /dev/sdX4 /mnt
   ```
10. Install barebones Ubuntu (replacing `bionic` with the codename of the Ubuntu version you want to install):

    ```
    debootstrap bionic /mnt
    ```
11. Set the hostname of your new Ubuntu installation (replacing `HOSTNAME` with your desired hostname):

    ```
    echo HOSTNAME > /mnt/etc/hostname
    ```
12. Configure package sources by writing the following content into `/mnt/etc/apt/sources.list` (replacing `bionic` with the codename of the Ubuntu version you installed):

    ```
    deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
    deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe

    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
    deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe

    deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
    deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe
    ```
13. Prepare to log in to the new Ubuntu system:

    ```
    mount --rbind /dev  /mnt/dev
    mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
    mount --rbind /sys  /mnt/sys
    ```
14. Log in to your new Ubuntu system:

    ```
    chroot /mnt /bin/bash --login
    ```
15. Configure the locale (modify as desired):

    ```
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
    echo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 > /etc/default/locale
    ```
16. Install the rest of Ubuntu Desktop (replace `ubuntu-desktop` with the flavor you want, if you don't want Ubuntu Desktop):

    ```
    dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
    ln -s /proc/self/mounts /etc/mtab
    apt update
    apt install -y ubuntu-desktop
    ```
17. Install GRUB for legacy boot:

    ```
    apt install -y grub-pc
    ```
18. Set up the EFI file system and install GRUB for EFI boot:

    ```
    apt install -y dosfstools
    mkdosfs -F 32 -n EFI /dev/sdX2
    mkdir /boot/efi
    echo PARTUUID=$(blkid -s PARTUUID -o value /dev/sdX2) /boot/efi vfat nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1 0 1 >> /etc/fstab
    mount /boot/efi
    apt install -y grub-efi-amd64
    ```
19. Configure GRUB for legacy boot:

    ```
    grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdX
    ```
20. Configure GRUB for EFI boot:

    ```
    grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sdX
    ```
21. Update the initrd files:

    ```
    update-initramfs -ckall
    ```
22. Update the GRUB boot configuration:

    ```
    update-grub
    ```
23. Clean up by exiting the chroot and unmounting:

    ```
    exit
    umount -R /mnt
    ```

You should now have Ubuntu installed on your disk with the ability to boot in EFI mode or in legacy mode.

`/dev/sdX3` is the data partition you requested.  You can format this with a Windows-compatible file system as desired.

---

### Acknowledgements

I pieced together this guide from two different sources:

- [The install script from aguslr's MultiBoot USB](https://github.com/aguslr/multibootusb/blob/master/makeUSB.sh)
- [ZFS on Linux's Ubuntu 16.04 Root on ZFS installation instructions](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Root-on-ZFS)

Comment: Thanks a lot! With a few small modifications, it worked like a charm!